# Повторное изменение атрибута id с помощью JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня одна форма для создания и редактирования задачи.

По нажатию на редактирование я изменяю id кнопки для отправки на обновления...

```
$('#submit-event').attr("id", '#edit-event')
```

Все работает, но после отправки или при нажатии на кнопку СОЗДАТЬ ЗАДАЧУ я должен стереть текущие данные и кнопку EDIT снова сделать для создания задачи

```
$('#event-text').val('')
$('#start').val('')
$('#end').val('')
$('#details').val('')
$('#edit-event').attr("id", 'submit-event')
$('#edit-task-id').attr('taskeditid', '')
```

Отрабатывает весь код кроме

```
$('#edit-event').attr("id", 'submit-event')
```

Как решить проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#submit-event').attr("id", '#edit-event')
```

здесь вы меняете `id` элемента на `'#edit-event'`

```
$('#edit-event').attr("id", 'submit-event')
```

здесь вы ищите элемент с `id = 'submit-event'`, так как значение `id` данного элемента немного другое, то селектор не находит нужный элемент и команда не срабатывает.

В JQuery эта самая решёточка вначале (`#`), означает что это `id` элемента, который нужно найти, то есть изначально надо менять `id` как-то так :

```
$('#submit-event').attr("id", 'edit-event')
```

Comment: спасибо. глуппая ошибка